# SQL reporting services , no dataset available

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to create a new dataset but the Create button is disabled in the SQL reporting services.If I click on the **Browse other data sources**  , I am only able to see my web reporting link.How can I create a **rsds** file and save it on my computer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to Open Report Builder with Run as Administrator.

Comment: You need to select a legitimate datasource before you can create datasets. You should be connecting to a SQL Server database for your datasource.

Comment: I am able to create an embedded connection but I am looking to use a shared connection for my report.

Answer (score 0):

To create the shared connection,it should be done from the web reporter link itself.

Once done, it can be found when browsing for it.

[image]

[image]